# Sinatra App clears session/cookie

Tags: session, cookies, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

I've been developing a Sinatra app using rackup as a server. Now it's time to deploy using Nginx & Unicorn.

I'm running into an issue where sessions are not being set properly. For example, I have Rack::Csrf, which comes up with an invalid token. Also, trying to set basic sessions for login does not work.

Here are the relevant lines. **My app.rb**

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :path => '/'
```

**Nginx conf**

```
upstream subdomain.domain.com {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock
    fail_timeout=0;
}


server {

server_name subdomain.domain.com;

root /home/user/app/public;
# port to listen for requests on
listen 1.1.2.3.4;

client_max_body_size 4G;

keepalive_timeout 5;

location / {
  try_files $uri @app;
}

location @app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http://subdomain.domain.com;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, because I placed

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, key: 'rack.session',
    domain: 'mydomain.com',
    path: '/',
    expire_after: 2592000,
    secret: ENV['SESSION_SECRET']
```

in config.ru file. When I moved this to Sinatra configure block the problem disappears.

Answer (score -1):

It seems I needed to set a domain

use Rack::Session::Cookie, :domain=>'subdomain.domain.com', :path => '/'

Not sure why in development using rackup there was no need to